# Can I put a form input in a react component?

Tags: reactjs

Usually my forms are super long, I would like to use them as components in separate files, I tried doing so but I can no longer modify the values, I mean there's two steps in this config,

first I need to pass initial values from the API fetch request, I used props like demonstrated below :

```
// in parent

   <InvoiceDetails {...this.state} />

// in component

...

render() {
let { invoicenumber, ponumber, invoicedate, paymentdue, loading } = this.props;
 return (
   <div>
   {!loading ?
   <Form>

   <Input fluid value={invoicenumber}
   type="text" onChange={this.handleForm}
   placeholder="Invoice number" name="invoicenumberEdit" />

   <DateInput
   autoComplete="off"
   name="invoicedate"
   placeholder="Invoice date"
   dateFormat='MMMM Do YYYY'
   value={invoicedate}
   clearable icon={false}
   clearIcon={<Icon name="remove" color="black" />}
   onChange={this.handleInvoiceDate}
   />

   ...
```

The functions that update those inputs are changing the parent state, so I couldn't move them to the component file because that would be two separate states.

```
   handleInvoiceDate = (event, { name, value }) => {
      if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
         this.setState({ [name]: value });
      }
   }

   handleForm = e => {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   };
```

I don't use context, redux or anything like that. How can I solve this if possible?

Comment: You can pass an `onChange` handler down from the parent and call it from the child - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0):

In your parent, make your handler a pure set state like this

```
handleInputChange = (name, value) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

then pass your handler as props like this

```
<InvoiceDetails {...this.state} handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

then in your component, add these functions to your code

```
 handleInvoiceDate = (event, { name, value }) => {
    if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
       this.props.handleInputChange(name, value);
    }
 }

 handleForm = e => {
    this.props.handleInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your function's from parent to child component as a `props` like,

```
<InvoiceDetails {...this.state} handleForm={this.handleForm} handleInvoiceDate={this.handleInvoiceDate}/>
```

Function's in parent,

```
handleInvoiceDate = (name, value ) => {
   if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
   }
}

handleForm = (name, value) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

In your component call these function's like,

```
<Input fluid value={invoicenumber}
   type="text" onChange={(e)=>this.props.handleForm(e.target.name,e.target.value)}
   placeholder="Invoice number" name="invoicenumberEdit" 
/>

<DateInput
   ...
   onChange={(e)=>this.props.handleInvoiceDate(e.target.name,e.target.value)}
/>
```